# Search Bar Icon not shown | React native

Tags: react-native, icons, uisearchbar

Search icon is replaced by some other icon. How to put icon in SearchBar (React-native-elements || React-native)
screenshot of the icon.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found The solution.
For some react-native versions, we need to manually link the module. In this case, i had to link react-native-vector-icons.

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons--save

react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

from project directory.

Comment: I have the same problem with:
- react-native 0.62.2
- react-native-elements ^1.2.7
- react-native-vector-icons: ^6.6.0
I cannot resolve it even run the ```link``` command.

Comment: @ThachHuynh I managed to resolve it by following the instructions from a Github: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#installation after you are done following the what's not. shutdown your machine and start it up again after like 10secs? I skipped the step whereby it ask me to copy the fonts from react-native-elements folder into the android assets/fonts folder in my RN project.

Answer (score 0):

I did these:

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons--save

react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

and then close the app from emulator uninstall it just to be on the safe side then:

```
npm start

react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which I have just managed to resolve for my project just now.
Just follow the instructions:
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#installation

I encountered an error that prompted me to have duplicate fonts. You may want to skip the part where it mentioned copying the Fonts folder from react-native-elements and placing it into the src/assets/fonts folder that resides in your react native project.

Shut down your laptop and then wait for about 10s before booting back up. I hope it helps whoever encountering the same issue as me (or us).

Just want to share the versions used in my project -

dependencies": {

```
..
**"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.3",
"react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.0.1",
"react-native-screens": "^3.12.0",**
...
**"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0"**
```

},

Answer (score 0):

I think i have encountered this once and solved it by adding this line at the end of android>app>build.gradle

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

then doing ./gradlew clean , and running the app again

Answer (score -1):

Here the code from documentation:

```
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'

<Icon
  name='rowing' />

<Icon
  name='g-translate'
  color='#00aced' />

<Icon
  name='sc-telegram'
  type='evilicon'
  color='#517fa4'
/>

<Icon
  reverse
  name='ios-american-football'
  type='ionicon'
  color='#517fa4'
/>

<Icon
  raised
  name='heartbeat'
  type='font-awesome'
  color='#f50'
  onPress={() => console.log('hello')} />
```

Comment: The icon should be show inside search bar. So this doesn't make sense. Can somebody help to import or include icon in search bar.

Comment: Icon can't be imported from react-native-elements Icon has a specific package name: react-native-vector-icons